# VSCode shows the code in black on grey after OS update

Tags: visual-studio-code

After updating my macbook to macOS Big Sur, VSCode's code part shows the code in black on grey, there is not any other color:

[image]

- VSCode Version: 1.51.1
- Electron: 9.3.3
- Chrome: 83.0.4103.122
- Node.js: 12.14.1
- V8: 8.3.110.13-electron.0
- OS: Darwin x64 20.1.0
- OS Version: macOS Big Sur 11.0.1

Comment: have you tried with `disable hardware acceleration`

Comment: For others you get to this question, there are lots of good comments at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/100840 about why this occurs and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Is your font family Source Code Pro too, reinstall it from google fonts works for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the VScode theme by clicking `Code > Preferences > Color Theme` and then using the up/down arrow keys to filter through the themes.

After (hopefully) finding one that fixes it, press enter.

More, [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes)